# Eine leichte Erkennungsregel für Transitivität eines Verbs

Tags: grammar-identification, passive

Grüße,

mit meiner Sprachpartnerin habe ich heute ein schwieriges Problem entdeckt.

Intransitive Verben könnne nicht im Passiv stehen.
Quelle:

- https://www.thoughtco.com/transitive-and-intransitive-verbs-1444720
- https://www.thoughtco.com/the-passive-voice-in-german-4068771

Für Fremdsprachler ist das ausgesprochen dramatisch, weil es nicht nachvollziehbar ist, warum die folgenden Beispiele gelten:

---

- Wir werden gefolgt - Nicht OK
- Uns wird gefolgt - OK

---

- Wir werden verfolgt - OK
- Uns wird verfolgt - Nicht OK

---

- Wir werden beraten  - OK
- Uns wird beraten - Nicht OK

---

- Wir werden geglaubt - Nicht OK
- Uns wird geglaubt - OK

---

Gibt es eine Regel, die auch Fremdsprachler intuitiv verwenden können, um zu unterscheiden, ob ein Verb transitiv oder intransitiv ist?

Oder ist das etwas, was man sich durch stumpfe Wiederholung einprägen muss?

Ich lerne beispielsweise aktuell Japanisch und da gelten folgende 3 Regeln:

1. Endet das Verb in -aru, ist es intransitiv.
2. Endet es in -su, ist es transitiv.
3. Gehört das Verb zu einem Verbpaar dann gilt: Ist Verb 1 durch Regel 1 oder 2 bestimmbar, dann hat Verb 2 die gegenteilige Transitivität.
   In allen anderen Fällen muss man die Transitivität auswändig lernen.

Gibt es ähnliche Regeln im Deutschen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leider gibt es keine "harte Regel", nach der sich auf Anhieb sagen ließe, ob ein Verb transitiv ist oder nicht. Das muss man ganz einfach lernen.

Um die Sache noch etwas schwieriger zu machen, gibt es ursprünglich intransitive Verben, die durchaus in Sonderfällen in transitiven Konstruktionen verwendet werden (und damit auch passiv-ähnliche Konstruktionen bilden können) - und umgekehrt. Ein paar Beispiele:

> Das Wasser kocht - Der Koch kocht Wasser

> Der Ast bricht - Der Wind (zer)bricht den Ast

Ein auch schönes Beispiel für Sonderfälle sind passiv-ähnliche Konstruktionen mit Verben, die ansonsten eigentlich kein Passiv bilden können:

> Geld in noch nie gehabten Mengen

> Eine Tat nie gekannter Grausamkeit

> ein Problem nie gewußter Komplexität

Es ist deswegen sinnvoll, deutsche Verben nicht einfach als einzelnes Wort, sondern als *Phrase* zu lernen, also anstatt z.B.

> geben == to give

solltest du

> jemandem etwas geben == to give something to somebody

memorieren. Das ist das, was deutschsprachige Kinder in der Schule lernen und man merkt sich auch gleich, welchen Kasus das Verb für welches Objekt erwartet.

Comment: Die transitive Verwendung von *kochen* und *brechen* sehe ich nicht als Ausnahmefall, sondern diese Verben können einfach sowohl transitiv als auch intransitiv verwendet weden. Wobei hier noch die Situation vorliegt, dass das Objekt des transitiv verwendeten Verbs beim intransitiven Verb zum Subjekt wird - das Verb wird dann in sog. *antikausativer* Weise verwendet.

Comment: @RHa zusammengefasst sagst du also "das ist kein Sonderfall, aber es ist ein Sonderfall". Aha. :)

Comment: Nein, es ist kein Sonderfall, sondern nur einer von zwei Fällen. Wenn überhaupt, ist der intranstive Fall ein Sonderfall, wegen der Antikausativität.

Answer (score 4):

Dass kein Passiv von intransitiven Verben gebildet werden kann, ist so nicht ganz richtig, denn auch von intransitiven Verben kann meist ein sogenanntes unpersönliches oder subjektloses Passiv gibildet weden. *Uns wird gefolgt* ist genau so ein Beispiel, denn *folgen* ist intransitiv, weil es nur mit Dativobjekt verwendet wird, nicht aber mit Akkusativobjekt.

Eine Ausnahme sind die nicht passivfähigen Verben, von denen auch kein unpersöliches Passiv gebildet werden kann. Beispiele sind die Verben *sein* und *werden*. Dies sind überwiegend Verben, die keine durch das Subjekt bewirkte Handlung, sondern eher einen Zustand ausdrücken.

Es gibt ein paar Regeln zu transitiven und intransitiven Verben, die aber nicht ausreichen, um auf einfache Weise bestimmen zu können, ob ein Verb transitiv ist oder nicht.

So sind Verben mit dem Präfix be- in der Regel transitiv. Beispiel: wirken (intransitiv) / bewirken (transitiv).

Bei Paaren von schwachen und starken Verben ist generell das schwache Verb transitiv und das starke Verb intransitiv. Beispiele: stellen (schwach, transitiv) / stehen (stark, intransitiv), legen (schwach, transitiv) / liegen (stark, intransitiv)

Answer (score 3):

Die Grammatikerklärungen auf thoughtco.com, die du verlinkt hast, enthalten etliche Irrtümer, ich würd mich auf die Seite nicht verlassen.

Deine Frage zielt eigentlich darauf, ob ein Objekt im Dativ oder Akkusativ stehen wird (daneben gibt es übrigens auch Objekte, die mit Präposition eingeleitet werden, und im geschriebenen Deutsch selten Genitiv-Objekte). Ich find es nicht hilfreich, alle Verben als "intransitiv" zu bezeichnen, die lediglich kein Akkusativobjekt haben. Denn das ist dann eine uneinheitliche Gruppe: Verben ohne Objekt oder mit anderen Objekten.

Wenn man nur die *Anzahl* der Objekte betrachtet, fühlt man sich zunächst nicht so unsicher: Da hat man von der Bedeutung und vom Englischen her oft ein ganz gutes Gefühl, wie viele Ergänzungen erwartet werden. Nur welchen Kasus sie kriegen, kann im Deutschen unregelmäßig sein. Die Strategie ist halt, sich die Verben extra zu merken, die Dativ- oder Präpositionalobjekte haben. Wenn man ja sowieso das Verb lernen muss...

Vorauszusagen, welche Verben ein Passiv erlauben und welche nicht, ist m.E. besonders schwierig und subtil, das eignet sich nicht als Test für Transitivität, sondern eher nur umgekehrt. Manche Verben mit Akkusativobjekt können nicht passiviert werden, manche Verben mit Dativobjekt können mit "bekommen" passiviert werden, andere nicht... Auch das unpersönliche Passiv geht nicht mit allen "intransitiven" Verben. Es ist einfacher, wenn man halt den Objektskasus mit dem Verb mitlernt. (Und erst wenn man den Kasus weiß, dann gibt es von da aus Regeln, wie ein Passiv aussehen kann, soweit Passivierung akzeptabel ist.)

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt solche Regeln leider nicht. Sie muss für jedes Verb lernen, welche Objekte es haben will. Am besten als ganze Verbphrase

- jemanden sehen (Akkusativobjekt)
- jemandem helfen (Dativobjekt)
- jemandes gedenken (Genitivobjekt)
- jemandem etwas(Akk) erklären (Dativobjekt, Akkusativobjekt)
- jemanden etwas(Akk) lehren (zwei Akkusativobjekte)
- auf jemanden warten (Präpositionalobjekt)
- …

Transitiv sind dann alle Verben, die ein Akkusativobjekt haben. Von diesen kann ein Passiv mit Subjekt gebildet werden. Von den anderen Verben nur ein subjektloses Passiv. Aber auch das geht nicht bei allen. Außerdem gibt es noch ein paar Verben, bei denen man ein Passiv mit *bekommen* bilden kann, wobei dann das Dativobjekt zum Subjekt wird.

Answer (score 0):

##### Deine Frage:

- Gibt es eine Regel, die auch Ausländer intuitiv verwenden können, um zu unterscheiden, ob ein Verb transitiv oder intransitiv ist?

  <sup>*(Zur falschen Verwendung von »Ausländer« (richtig wäre: »fremdsprachige Menschen«) habe ich schon etwas in einem Kommentar unter deiner Frage geschrieben.)*</sup>

##### kurze Antwort

Nein.

##### lange Antwort

Du wirfst mehrere unterschiedliche Eigenschaften von Verben in einen Topf und versuchst sie als gleich zu behandeln, obwohl es sich um unterschiedliche Eigenschaften handelt, die zwar miteinander verbunden sind, aber eben doch auch verschieden voneinander sind. Diese Eigenschaften sind:

- die Möglichkeit, in einer Passiv-Konstruktion verwendet zu werden
- Transitivität

Die Transitivität ist wiederum eng damit verknüpft, ob ein Verb ein Akkusativobjekt haben muss, haben kann, oder nicht haben kann:

- **echt transitiv:** Das Verb muss in einem Aktivsatz zwingend mit einem Akkusativobjekt verwendet werden.

  - falsch: Ich brauche. Ich habe. Ich freue.
  - richtig: Ich brauche das Geld. Ich habe einen Mantel. Ich freue mich.
- **(einfach) transitiv:** Das Verb kann in einem Aktivsatz mit oder ohne Akkusativobjekt verwendet werden.

  - möglich (intransitive Verwendung): Ich singe.
  - möglich (transitive Verwendung): Ich singe ein Lied.
- **intransitiv:** Es ist falsch, das Verb mit einem Akkusativobjekt zu verwenden

  - falsch (mit Akkusativobjekt): Das gehört dich. Ich arbeite den Fall.
  - richtig (mit Dativobjekt): Das gehört dir.
  - richtig (mit Präpositionalobjekt): Das gehört zu meinen Aufgaben. Ich arbeite an dem Fall.

###### Passiv

Das, was man als erstes über die Konstruktion von passiven Sätzen lernt, ist das:

1. Man nimmt einen Aktiv-Satz, in dem ein Akkusativ-Objekt vorkommt, und macht daraus das Subjekt, das an den Anfang des Satzes kommt.
2. Dann kommt ein Hilfsverb. Will man einen Vorgangspassiv bilden, verwendet man eine Form des Hilfsverbs *»werden«,* will man einen Zustandspassiv bilden, dann greift man zu einer Form von *»sein«.*
3. Der optionale dritte Teil ist ein Präpositionalobjekt, das mit der Präposition "von" beginnt und anschließend jenen Teil im Dativ enthält, der im Aktiv-Satz das Subjekt war.
4. Am Ende muss noch das Verb aus dem Aktiv-Satz stehen, diesmal aber in einer anderen Form, nämlich als Partizip II (Partizip Perfekt)

Beispiel:

> Aktiv: **Der Förster rodet den Wald.**
> Vorgangspassiv mit Präpositionalobjekt: **Der Wald wird vom Förster gerodet.** ("vom" = "von dem")
> Vorgangspassiv ohne Präpositionalobjekt: **Der Wald wird gerodet.**
> Zustandspassiv (üblicherweise ohne Präpositionalobjekt): **Der Wald ist gerodet.**

So, wie gerade eben beschrieben, funktioniert da auch in den allermeisten Fällen.

###### Akkusativobjekt aber trotzdem kein Passiv möglich

Aber leider gibt es auch viele Ausnahmen:

- richtig: Ich brauche das Geld. → Das Geld wird (von mir) gebraucht.
- falsch: Ich habe einen Mantel. → <del>Der Mantel wird (von mir) gehabt.</del>
- falsch: Ich freue mich. → <del>Ich werde (von mir) gefreut.</del>

Warum ist das so? Die Verben *»brauchen«, »haben«* und *»freuen«* benötigen doch alle drei zwingend ein Akkusativobjekt, aber von diesen dreien eignet sich nur *»brauchen«* für die Bildung eines Passiv-Satzes. Warum geht das nicht mit *»haben«* und *»freuen«*?

- **echt reflexive Verben mit Akkusativobjekt**
  Fangen wir mit "freuen" an. Dieses Verb gehört zur Gruppe der echten reflexiven Verben mit Akkusativobjekt. Das sind Verben, die zwar zwingend ein Akkusativobjekt haben müssen, was sie formal zu echten transitiven Verben macht, aber dieses Akkusativobjekt muss zwingend ein Reflexivpronomen sein, also ein Pronomen, das auf das Subjekt referenziert. Hier sind Beispiele (das Reflexivpronomen ist fett markiert):

  > Ich freue **mich.** Du schämst **dich.** Ich befinde **mich** an einem Ort. Er interessiert **sich** für Geschichte. Wir irren **uns.** Ihr bedankt **euch.**

  Mit keinem dieser Verben kann man einen Passiv-Satz bilden.

  Zu ergänzen ist, dass es auch echte reflexive Verben mit Dativobjekt gibt (*»Ich nehme **mir** Urlaub.«*) die ohnehin keine Untergruppe der transitiven Verben sind.

  Es gibt aber auch transitive Verben, die sowohl reflexiv als auch nichtreflexiv verwendet werden können. In diesem Fall gelingt die Bildung des Passivs wenn das Verb nicht reflexiv verwendet wird:

  > richtig: Ich wasche meine Hemden. → Meine Hemden werden gewaschen.
  > falsch: Ich wasche mich.  → <del>Ich werde gewaschen.</del>

  Der Satz *»Ich werde gewaschen«* ist zwar  grammatisch korrekt, aber er ist nicht die Passiv-Form von *»Ich wasche mich.«* Der Satz *»Ich werde gewaschen«* sagt nämlich aus, dass eine andere Person als ich selbst mich wäscht. z.B. *»Der Krankenpfleger wäscht mich.«* Das ist dann aber keine reflexive Verwendung des Verbs *»waschen«.*
- **andere nicht-passivfähige Verben mit Akkusativobjekt**
  Das Verb *»haben«* gehört in diese Gruppe. Das sind Verben, die zwar in einem Aktivsatz ein Akkusativobjekt benötigen oder zumindest haben können, die man aber trotzdem nicht in Passiv-Sätzen verwenden kann.

  Hier sind Beispiele:

  > Ich habe einen Mantel. → <del>Der Mantel wird gehabt.</del>

  Die Verben *»haben«, »bekommen«, »behalten«, »besitzen«* und *»kriegen«* können keinen Passiv bilden.

  > Das Auto kostet sehr viel Geld. → <del>Sehr viel Geld wird gekostet.</del>

  Wenn das Akkusativobjekt eine Mengenangabe ist, ist die Bildung des Passiv nicht möglich.

  > Er geht seinen Weg. → Sein Weg wird gegangen.

  Verben der Fortbewegung (*»gehen«, laufen, schwimmen, fliegen, ...*) werden meist ohne Akkusativobjekt verwendet. Wenn es doch eines gibt, benennt es die Strecke oder den Weg, entlang dessen die Bewegung verläuft (*»Er läuft einen Marathon.«*) In diesem Fall kann man auch die Passivform bilden (*»Der Marathon wurde gelaufen«*). Das gelingt aber nicht mehr, wenn man die Bewegung im übertragenen Sinn meint (*»jemand geht seinen Weg« = »jemand erreicht die selbstgesteckten Ziele«*) denn durch die Bildung des Passivs geht die übertragene Bedeutung verloren, und es kommt die wörtliche Bedeutung (physische Strecke) hervor.

  Es gibt noch weitere Verben, die zwar im Aktiv mit einem Akkusativobjekt verwendet werden, die aber trotzdem nicht passivfähig sind.

  Leider gibt es keine einfachen Regeln, anhand derer man das leicht erkennen kann.

###### Passiv ohne Akkusativobjekt

> Aktiv: Der Mann hilft mir.

In diesem Satz gibt es kein Akkusativobjekt. Tatsächlich gehört das Verb *»helfen«* sogar zu den Verben, bei denen es falsch wäre, sie mit einem Akkusativobjekt zu verwenden. Trotzdem kann man daraus einen Passivsatz machen:

> Passiv: Mir wird (von dem Mann) geholfen.

Das besondere an dieser Konstruktion ist, dass darin - zumindest im grammatischen Sinn - kein Subjekt vorkommt. Semantisch und logisch ist "mir" das Subjekt, aber grammatisch ist das anders. Das Wort "mir" ist dasselbe Dativobjekt, das es schon im Aktivsatz war (hier ein "Dativus commodi", also ein Dativ, der die Person benennt, die einen Vorteil aus der Handlung hat).

> Aktiv: Die Leute warten schon seit Stunden auf den Zug.
> Passiv: Auf den Zug wird schon seit Stunden gewartet.

Die Situation ist ähnlich wie zuvor. Das Verb *»warten«* kann nicht mit einem Akkusativobjekt verwendet werden. Stattdessen erscheint es hier mit zwei Präpositionalobjekten. Der Passiv-Satz enthält auch diesmal kein Subjekt. Er wird dadurch gebildet, dass eines der beiden Präpositionalobjekte vor das Hilfsverb gestellt wird, und das andere dahinter.

> Aktiv: Das Publikum klatscht.
> Passiv: Es wird geklatscht.

Auch *»klatschen«* kann nicht mit einem Akkusativobjekt verwendet werden. In diesem Fall gibt es im Aktiv-Satz überhaupt kein Objekt. Es gibt nur das Subjekt, das im Passiv-Satz aber nicht vorkommt. Hier wird der Passiv-Satz mit einem expletiven Subjekt gebildet. Das ist das Wort *»es«,* das hier nicht als Pronomen fungiert (dieses Wort referenziert hier auf nichts), sondern nur ein reiner Platzhalter ist, damit irgendetwas die Position 1 ausfüllt, so dass das Hilfsverb an Position 2 stehen kann. Das Wort *»es«* ist zwar grammatikalisch das Subjekt, denn es steht im Nominativ, aber es hat keine semantische Bedeutung.

> Aktiv: Man raucht hier nicht.
> Passiv: Hier wird nicht geraucht.

Das Verb *»rauchen«* kann zwar mit einem Akkusativobjekt verwendet werden (*»Man raucht Zigarren«*), aber das ist hier nicht der Fall. Auch das ist ein unpersönlicher Passiv ohne Subjekt.

Zu ergänzen ist auch noch, dass das Fehlen eines Subjekts noch kein Grund ist, dass ein Satz als Passiv-Satz gelten muss. Der Satz *»Mich friert«* enthält zwar auch kein Subjekt, ist aber trotzdem ein Aktiv-Satz, weil das Verb in seiner normalen Aktiv-Form verwendet wird. Die Passiv-Form wäre *»wird gefroren«* oder *»ist gefroren«.*

Comment: "behalten" kann keinen Passiv bilden? Ist "Spieler X wird im Team behalten." keine Passiv-Konstruktion?